# Why does this code not back-up/ZIP directories?

Tags: python, zip

I'm making a program to ZIP files. In this scenario, I am trying to ZIP a directory, with a subdirectory inside of it. I'm using the following function if the program has to ZIP a directory, yet it doesn't ZIP subdirectories, it just takes the files from the subdirectory and puts them with all the others.

```
zipper = zipfile.ZipFile(systemDate + ".zip", "w")

def zipdir(path, ziph):
    logging.info("ZIP function has been called.")
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            fileNom = os.path.join(root, file)
            print("file nom: " + fileNom)
            zipper.write(fileNom, basename(fileNom))
```

Thanks.

Comment: You have to give a bit more context. How does the rest of the program look like?

Comment: This function is the only part of the program which handles the zipping of directories, I don't think the rest of the program would be beneficial. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second argument to `ZipFile.write` is the archive name, i.e. the filename of the file inside the archive. Since the ZIP file does not contain any folder information on its own, *that* is where that has to go. So in order to put a file inside a subdirectory, you have to adjust the `arcname` to include a directory name.

You can use [`os.path.relpath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.relpath) to calculate a path relative to your `path` which appears to be the root of the ZIP file:

```
zipper.write(fileNom, os.path.relpath(fileNom, path))
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll give this a go.